# php7 void return type not working?

Tags: php, return-type, type-hinting, php-7

I have a problem with return types in php7, specially "void".

it works with all other types, int, string, null, bool, class objects.

but when i use void it expecting me to return an instance of object void but in reality it should not expect any return as thats what void is for.

note: I'm running PHP 7.0.3

here is the code:

```
   public static function setResponseCode(int $code) : void
    {
        http_response_code($code);

    }
```

and error message is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Return value of CodeBase\HttpRequester::setResponseCode() must be an instance of void, none returned in /var/www/html/src/HttpRequester.php:86 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(103): CodeBase\HttpRequester::setResponseCode(500) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/src/HttpRequester.php on line 86

Comment: Try adding a `return;` which is valid. As `http_response_code` returns a value, maybe it is getting confused and thinking that result is being returned

Comment: @RiggsFolly or maybe there is no such thing (yet) as a void return type :)

Comment: @PeeHaa Ah yes forgot I was reading the RFC Docs

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's fine to use `http_response_code();`, you're not returning what it is.

Comment: simply don't use this feature!

Comment: It can be useful for more readability. I've just checked, it will be possible in PHP 7.1 : https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type

Comment: If anyone is tempted, please don't listen to the terrible advice of @MumenYassin. Please do use return types, and update your php versions. Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Void return types are for PHP 7.1 (which had not yet been released when you asked this). [From the RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type)

> Version: 0.2.1
>   Date: 2015-02-14 (v0.1, later withdrawn), 2015-10-14 (v0.2, revival)
>   Author: Andrea Faulds, ajf@ajf.me
>   **Status: Implemented (PHP 7.1)**

Answer (score 15):

I've just found the answer here: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type

It will be a feature in PHP 7.1

Comment: So basically, the answer is "not yet but soon(tm)"

Answer (score 8):

No there is not, until PHP 7.1. For PHP 7.0, you have to omit the return type completely for `void` functions/methods.

```
function printLn($a) {
    echo "$a\n";
}
```

Unfortunately, you then have no type safety for this function/method, and no `TypeError` will be thrown if you start returning something from it.

Luckily, [PHP 7.1 fixes this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type):

> Support for a new void return type is added. It requires that a function not return any value.

**This is the correct syntax for PHP 7.1**:

```
function should_return_nothing(): void {
    return 1; // Fatal error: A void function must not return a value
}
```

This was postponed during [the proposal that created return type hints](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types):

> **We keep the current type options**. Past proposals have suggested new types such as void, int, string or scalar; this RFC does not include any new types. Note that it does allow self and parent to be used as return types.
>   ...
>
> **Future Work**
>
> **Ideas for future work which are out of the scope of this RFC include**:
>
> - Allow functions to declare that they do not return anything at all (void in Java and C)

`NULL` also is not allowed as a return type.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

Return type void works since PHP 7.1 which is already available.

Working syntax is:

```
<?php
function procedure(): void
{
//  return 'will not work';
}

echo procedure();
```