# Symfony 4 deployment not working

Tags: production-environment, symfony4

I'm trying to deploy a symfony 4 project in my server, but I'm having problems to acomplish it production (in local it works perfect).

Previously I have deployed a lot of symfony 3 projects in my server, so I decided to test a Symfony 4.

This is the error that I'm getting in my log:

> [Wed Dec 06 10:26:33.141952 2017] [:error] [pid 13485] [client 84.120.210.249:50394] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv::populate() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Dotenv\void, none returned in /var/www/my_project/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:95\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/my_project/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(57): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->populate(Array)\n#1 /var/www/my_project/public/index.php(15): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->load('/var/www/rodage...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/my_project/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 95

This is my index.php (default index.php that you get when you create a project):

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// The check is to ensure we don't use .env in production
if (!isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV'])) {
    if (!class_exists(Dotenv::class)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('APP_ENV environment variable is not defined. You need to define environment variables for configuration or add "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer dependency to load variables from a .env file.');
    }
    (new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');
}

if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ?? ('prod' !== ($_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev'))) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}

if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
}

if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts(explode(',', $trustedHosts));
}

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev', $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ?? ('prod' !== ($_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev')));
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

This is what I have in my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "symfony/asset": "^4.0",
    "symfony/console": "^4.0",
    "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
},
```

These are the things that I tried:

-cache:clear

-composer update

-apache restart

I think that it something about environment variables, but not really sure...

Any suggestions?

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Void returns are only available from PHP 7.1. My guess is that you are using an earlier version of PHP.

[Look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482195/php7-void-return-type-not-working)

Comment: php -v:
PHP 7.1.12-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov 29 2017 10:03:25) ( NTS )

After editing my composer.json with dotenv 3.4 I got a new error...

PHP Fatal error:  Default value for parameters with a class type can only be NULL in /var/www/my_project/vendor/symfony/config/ResourceCheckerConfigCache.php 

There is no sense for this kind of errors. In localhost my app works perfect