# Symfony 4.1 error with Dotenv and void class

Tags: php, symfony4

hello everybody i'm under symfony 4.1 and i got this errors

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of 
Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv::populate() must be an instance of 
Symfony\Component\Dotenv\void, none returned in 
/var/www/mailx/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:95 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/mailx/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(57): 
Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->populate(Array) #1 
/var/www/mailx/public/index.php(15): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv- 
>load('/var/www/mailx/...') #2 {main} thrown in 
/var/www/mailx/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 95
```

this happen when try to open home page here is my config :

```
PHP 7.2.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun 22 2018 08:44:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

there is no extra code in my project, it's fresh Symfony

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it could be related to PHP version.  See related [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25469) on Github.

Some potential causes / fixes:

1. Depending on how you installed dotenv (see [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html)) you may need to get rid of vendor folder and run fresh composer install
2. Downgrade to PHP 7.0 as return types introduced in 7.1 hence the error (obviously not long term solution)

Comment: i saw that , but my project work before under another server with same php version and no issues were thrown

Comment: Wondering if you have a .env file in your project root.  Everything seems to be pointing at PHP version causing the error (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482195/php7-void-return-type-not-working).

Comment: yes my .env is in project folder and working fine with php cli when i migration database, i have performed a downgrade to php 7.1 reboot server and clear symfony  cache, i still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

well, for symfony 4.1 i don't really know but i downgrade symfony to 3.4 and faced the same problem and the solution is to set the mysql version in config file.

config.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ...
        server_version: "%database_server_version%"
```

parameters.yaml

```
parameters:
    ...
    database_server_version: 5.7
```